# Sum values in an associative multidimensional array according to a predefined and potentially incomplete key path

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sum, filtering, keypaths

I have problem with my arrays and `array_sum()` function.

This code is not working properly. I have commented what it should be printed.

```
$teams[1]['AREA I']['blue'] = 30;
$teams[1]['AREA I']['green'] = 25;
$teams[1]['AREA II']['blue'] = 15;
$teams[2]['AREA I']['blue'] = 40;

echo array_sum($teams[1]); // 30+25+15=70
echo array_sum($teams[1]['AREA I']); // 30+25=55
echo array_sum($teams[1]['AREA I']['blue']); // 30
```

Comment: Yes, you're using `array_sum` wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on below solution, hope it will help you to get desire result.
I used iterator to iterate array:

```
function getSum($array){
    if(is_array($array)) {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            $sum += $value;
        }
    } else{
        $sum = $array;
    }
    return $sum;
}

$teams = array();
$teams[1]['AREA I']['blue'] = 30;
$teams[1]['AREA I']['green'] = 25;
$teams[1]['AREA II']['blue'] = 15;
$teams[2]['AREA I']['blue'] = 40;

echo getSum($teams); //output: 110
echo getSum($teams[1]); //output: 70
echo getSum($teams[1]['AREA I']); //output: 55
echo getSum($teams[1]['AREA I']['blue']); //output: 30
```

Comment: Is there any way to skip some param? So that if I don't want to set any spesific area but I want to set colour. Then script sums all areas, but only for example blues?

Comment: you can add condition on basis of `$key` in `foreach` loop

Comment: @lingo if you want to "skip params", maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77786064/2943403) satisfies your meaning.

Answer (score 2):

array_sum — Calculate the sum of values in an array. As your array is multi dimensional so you should loop it. Try as below :

```
$teams[1]['AREA I']['blue'] = 30;
$teams[1]['AREA I']['green'] = 25;
$teams[1]['AREA II']['blue'] = 15;
$teams[2]['AREA I']['blue'] = 40;
$sum = 0;

foreach($teams as $num => $values) {
    if(is_array($values))
    {
        foreach($values as $num1 => $values1) {
            $sum += array_sum($values1);
        }
    }
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_sum()` expects an array to be passed as a parameter, so if you run your current code with `error_reporting` switched on it will throw back the following:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given -- at line 10

You are passing in the number 30 as an integer to a function that is expecting an array, so it errors and doesn't return what you're expecting.

You can read up on the function in the PHP Manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

You may also find the error reporting page helpful:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

As array_sum() works on single dimensional array, it will not work for your first and third case. It will only work for your second case which is as follows.

> echo array_sum($teams[1]['AREA I']);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive script which is designed to offer a high amount of flexibility while filtering.  Create an array of qualifying keys as a path. If any key qualifies at a given level, just use `null` as that level's qualifying key.

The only limitation that I am aware of is that partial keys and multiple keys per level are not accommodated.  I had to draw the line somewhere.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hsFqX))

```
$filterSets = [
    [],
    [1],
    [2],
    [null, 'AREA I'],
    [null, 'AREA II'],
    [null, null, 'blue'],
    [null, null, 'green'],
    [null, 'AREA I', 'blue'],
    ['foo'],
    [null, null, null, null],
];

function sumViaPath(array $array, array $path): int
{
    $sum = 0;
    $filterKey = $path ? array_shift($path) : null;
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($filterKey === null || $filterKey === $k) {
            $sum += is_array($v) ? sumViaPath($v, $path) : $v;
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}

foreach ($filterSets as $path) {
    $results[json_encode($path)] = sumViaPath($teams, $path);
}
var_export($results);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '[]' => 110,
  '[1]' => 70,
  '[2]' => 40,
  '[null,"AREA I"]' => 95,
  '[null,"AREA II"]' => 15,
  '[null,null,"blue"]' => 85,
  '[null,null,"green"]' => 25,
  '[null,"AREA I","blue"]' => 70,
  '["foo"]' => 0,
  '[null,null,null,null]' => 110,
)
```